# Get string element from ArrayList<E> with lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have an payload that returns the following `ArrayList`:

```
[0] true (boolean)
[1] "someStringValue"
```

I need to extract the value of the element that contains the `String` value using **lambda expression**.

Any ideas?

Comment: there is a fundamental difference between `ArrayList` and `ArrayList<E>`, please clarify which one you are referring to in your question

Comment: I refer to ArrayList<E> since I could not story my payload response in a simple arraylist

Comment: You can have  ArrayList<Object> ?

Comment: yes, I can replace ArrayList<E> to ArrayList<Object>

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Don't confuse **lambda** with the **Stream API** or **method references**. All three are different things. You probably want a solution using the **Stream API** (where lambdas and method references are often used) or **Java 8** stuff in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that you didn't specify what your `ArrayList` holds. I would assume it's `Object`. If it's however some container class then you need to adapt the code here and there a bit. Should be relatively easy. If you have difficulties, please don't bother commenting and giving additional information.

### Without Java 8

Let's first take a look at how you would do it without Streams or Lambda:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = ...

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
// Iterate all elements
for (Object obj : list) {
    // Ignore elements that are not of type String
    if (!(obj instanceof String)) {
        continue;
    }

    // The element is String, cast it
    String objAsText = (String) obj;
    // Collect it
    result.add(objAsText);
}
```

The list `result` now only contains elements of the original list whose *true type* were `String`.

---

### With Java 8 (Streams, Lambdas, Method references)

We can now easily write an equivalent version using the Stream API. Note that you probably confuse `Stream`s in general with Lambda (they are different technologies, though Lambdas are often used in the Stream-API).

```
ArrayList<Object> list = ...

result = list.stream()                // Stream<Object>
    .filter(String.class::isInstance) // Stream<Object>
    .map(String.class::cast)          // Stream<String>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That's it, quite easy and readable. The `Collection#stream` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--)) returns a `Stream` consisting of the elements in the given collection. The `Stream#filter` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)) method returns a `Stream` where the elements not matching the condition are skipped. The `Stream#map` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)) transforms a `Stream<X>` into a `Stream<Y>` by applying the given method to all objects (`X` can be equal `Y`). Finally the `Stream#collect` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)) method collects all elements by using the given `Collector`.

If you however truly wanted to use Lambdas, then this might be more what you want:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = ...
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

list.forEach(obj -> {    // This is a big lambda
    // Ignore elements that are not of type String
    if (!(obj instanceof String)) {
        return;
    }

    // The element is String, cast it
    String objAsText = (String) obj;
    // Collect it
    result.add(objAsText);
});
```

But I really think you confused the terms here.

Comment: yes, I confused ArrayList<E> with ArrayList<Object>. I used <Object> and worked well. I managed to extract the string value from my ArrayList<Object>

Comment: I recommend to be consistent regarding your choice between lambda expressions and method references. So use either `.filter(obj -> obj instanceof String) .map(obj -> (String) obj)` or `.filter(String.class::isInstance) .map(String.class::cast)`…

Comment: @Holger It's just that I didn't knew that cast reference yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this as a lambda you can do the following:

Assuming you have a collection as follows:

```
Collection<Object> collection = new ArrayList<Object>();
collection.add(true);
collection.add("someStringValue");

Collection<String> onlyStrings =  collection.stream()
          .filter(String.class::isInstance)
          .map(object -> (String) object)
          .collect(Collectors.toList() );

//Now you have a collection of only Strings.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `instanceof` and lambda expression:

```
ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>();

array.add(new Boolean(true));
array.add(new String("someStringValue"));


array.forEach(item->{
    if(item instanceof String){
        System.out.println(item);
    }
});
```

[Working example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

Answer (score 1):

**Hello, that's my suggestion:**

```
List<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();

array.add(Boolean.TRUE);
array.add("someStringValue");

array.stream().
      filter(String.class::isInstance).
      forEach((o) -> System.out.println("String = " + o));
```

**Hope this helps!**